# How to programmatically set a tab to be inactive or not clickable in TabbedPage

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have 3 tabs which base on permission.

This permission base on user level.

If user has higher level, he or she can have access the 3 tabs ( this means he or she can click all the tab)

Problem:

How do I programmatically set the tab3, say the user has no access to Tab3, to be dimmed or unclickabe?

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="myApp.View.MainPage2">

    <ContentPage Title ="Tab1" Icon="itemIcon1" WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="White">

        <ContentPage.Content>

            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">

                <Label Text="Welcome, Test1"> </Label>

            </StackLayout>

        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>

    <ContentPage Title ="Tab2" Icon="itemIcon2" WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="White">

        <ContentPage.Content>

            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">

                <Label Text="Welcome, Test2">  </Label>

            </StackLayout>

        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>


    <ContentPage Title ="Tab3" Icon="itemIcon3" WidthRequest="200">

        <ContentPage.Content>

            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Welcome, Test3"> </Label>
            </StackLayout>

        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can, at least not on iOS and if you would, it would probably be failed by the Apple review process because they think it's not user-friendly. I think you should find some way around it, let the user select the tab, but have it show some message to the user that the cannot use it right now or something. Depending on your use case.

Comment: good suggestion, How to I detect the click of the tab and do some logic and inform user he has no access? Thanks

Comment: and move to one of the tabs.

Comment: Why not have the page populate differently based on user level? Alternatively, why not have the tab invisible to lower level users?